# I used overlapping on image but the second image didn't show on the RWD(just the first pic have it)

Tags: html, css

I used overlapping on my pic. This is my code.

HTML

```
<div>
        <img src="thehall.png">
    <div class="c2">
        <img src="cards2.png" id="P2">
    </div>
    <div class="c3">
        <img src="cards3.png" id="P3">
    </div>
    <div class="c4">
        <img src="cards4.png" id="P4">
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(blackground30015.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

.container-fluid
{

    max-width: 100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

img
{
    max-width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}



#P2{
        position:fixed;
        left:32%;
        z-index:1;
        cursor: pointer;
        bottom: 40%;
    }
#P3{
        position:fixed;
        left:50%;
        z-index:1;
        cursor: pointer;
        bottom: 40%;
    }
#P4{
        position:fixed;
        left:68%;
        z-index:1;
        cursor: pointer;
        bottom: 40%;
    }
```

But the pic2 pic3 pic4 couldn't use by RWD.
When I narrowed the page that didn't scale with `thehall.png`.
How can I let the pic234 following up thehall zoom in.

I try to use max-width:100%, scale(x,y). It's also doesn't work or has other ways?
(ps. It's my first time to ask the question. if my question don't that you understand, I'm sorry.)

Comment: What's RWD? I don't know that term.

Comment: Googled it for anyone else wondering: it's just responsive web design.

Comment: It might not make a difference but your div container has a typo: calss -> class. And blackground30015.png should be inside quotation marks.